# How to implement CSRF protection in Ajax calls using express.js (looking for complete example)?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, csrf

I am trying to implement CSRF protection in an app built using node.js using the express.js framework. The app makes abundant use of Ajax post calls to the server. I understand that the connect framework provides CSRF middleware, but I am not sure how to implement it in the scope of client-side Ajax post requests.

There are bits and pieces about this in other Questions posted here in stackoverflow, but I have yet to find a reasonably complete example of how to implement it from both the client and server sides.

Does anyone have a working example they care to share on how to implement this? Most of the examples I have seen, assume you are rendering the form on the server-side and then sending it (along with the embedded csrf_token form field) to the client-side. In my app, all content is rendered on the client-side (including templates) via Backbone.js. All the server does is provide values in JSON format, which are utilized by various Models in Backbone.js on the client-side.  By my understanding I would need to retrieve the csrf_token via ajax first before it can be used.  However, I am concerned this may be problematic from a security standpoint. Is this a valid concern?

Answer (score 33):

It can be done by adding `meta` tag for CSRF token and then pass CSRF token with every Ajax request

## Server

Add CSRF middleware

```
app.use(express.csrf());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.token = req.session._csrf;
  next();
});
```

You can pass a CSRF token to the client side via, say, a meta tag. For ex, in `Jade`

```
meta(name="csrf-token", content="#{token}")
```

## Client

jQuery has a feature called ajaxPrefilter, which lets you provide a callback to be invoked every Ajax request. Then set a header using ajaxPrefilter.

```
var CSRF_HEADER = 'X-CSRF-Token';

var setCSRFToken = function (securityToken) {
  jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, _, xhr) {
    if (!xhr.crossDomain) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(CSRF_HEADER, securityToken);
    }
  });
};

setCSRFToken($('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
```

Comment: probably the best answer here

Comment: I disagree. It's a good answer but it doesn't address the lack of server-side rendering. It mentions using Jade to render a meta tag on the page. But that tag's value needs to be generated server side and since the original asker says that none of his views are generated server-side this won't work.

Comment: How can we validate this token in the server side?

Comment: @Bill I agree. The asker ask a solution for client-side render and the server-side only provide restful api.

Answer (score 6):

server.js

```
...
// All Cookies/Sessions/BodyParser go first
app.use(express.csrf());
...
// Get the request
app.post('/ajax', function(req, res){
    res.render('somelayout', {csrf_token: req.session._csrf});
});
```

In somelayout.jade

```
input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value=csrf_token)
```

The CSRF middleware only generates the csrf token once per session, so it will probably not change for the duration of a user's visit.

Also, it doesn't check for the token on GET and HEAD requests. As long as the token is in the request (header, body, or query), you're good. That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  In my app, all client side content is performed via ajax. Actual rendering of content (including templates) are performed on the client-side. All the server does is provide variable data to the client-side in JSON format. This would mean that I have to retreive the CSRF token via ajax to render it into the page so that it can then be sent back in the ajax post request. I am worried that this might be problematic from a security standpoint, is this a valid concern?

Comment: If you can, a good way to get the CSRF to the client is to render it out inside a `meta` tag (a la Rails) or something similar from Express.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `Backbone.js` for your application, I am assuming that it is a SPA and you initially load an `index.html` file, then make any other requests are made via `ajax` calls. If so, you can add a small snippet of JS code to your `index.html` file to hold the crsf token for any future `ajax` calls.

For example:

**index.html** (using Handlebars for templating...)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $( function() {
                window.Backbone.csrf = "{{csrfToken}}";
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

When you render the `index.html` file, give it the `csrf` token that the express framework generated here: `req.session._csrf`

When you use `Backbone.js`, it sets a global variable called `Backbone`. All that the previous function is doing is seting a property called `csrf` to the global `Backbone` object. And when you make an `ajax` call to `POST` data, simply add the `Backbone.csrf` variable to the data as `_csrf` that is being sent via the `ajax` call.

Answer (score 1):

In Server:

```
app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.locals._csrf = req.csrfToken();
  res.locals.csrf_form_html = '<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="' + req.csrfToken() + '" >';
  req.next();
});
```

In Client: (swig template)

```
var csrf = {{ _csrf|json|safe }};

$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': csrf
  }
});

$.post("/create", data, function(result) {
  console.log(result);
}).fail(function(){
  console.log(arguments);
});
```

Comment: How do you validate the token in the server side?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Add csrf protection middleware:

```
app.use(csrf({cookie: true}));

// csrf middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   res.cookie('X-CSRF-Token', req.csrfToken());
   // this line below is for using csrfToken value in normal forms (as a hidden input)
   res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken(); 
   next();
});

// routing setup goes here
```

**2.** Add a `beforeSend` callback using `$.ajaxSetup`: (add this somewhere before all your ajax calls)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
        // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", getCookie('X-CSRF-Token'));
    }
}
});
```

**3.** That's it!  now you can send ajax requests and you don't need to add anything in headers or as a request parameter to pass through csrf.