# Passing CSRF token to REACT/FLUX from node

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm using nodejs and usually pass down csrf token like the following:

util.js

```
module.exports.csrf = function csrf(req, res, next){
     res.locals.token = req.csrfToken();
     next();
￼￼};
```

app.js

```
app.use(csrf());
app.use(util.csrf);
```

and then in the ejs page I would do

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= token %>">
```

However, now I'm using flux/react for my front end and need to pass a csrf token for a form submission and not to sure how to do this. There was a similar answer here using jade:

[How to implement CSRF protection in Ajax calls using express.js (looking for complete example)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200068/how-to-implement-csrf-protection-in-ajax-calls-using-express-js-looking-for-com)

However, I'm using ejs (with jsx)(or just html) and don't want to use jade

Comment: Echoing Joel, I'd really suggest doing this in a outside of React. I'm fond of how angular's `$http` service handles this by looking for a session cookie, and including that on every outgoing XHR request.

Answer (score 8):

I have found the best way to do this in React is to add the `csrf` token to a store, or pass it to the component context.

You can see how its done by slightly altering the [Yahoo Fluxible react-router example](https://github.com/yahoo/flux-examples/blob/master/react-router/server.js).

```
context.executeAction(setTokenAction, req.csrfToken(), function(){});
```

This executes a flux action with the `csrf` token as a parameter.  The Yahoo flux architecture serializes the values of the store to the client via:

`var exposed = 'window.App=' + serialize(app.dehydrate(context)) + ';';`

This gets written out to the page in a script tag, which can then be accessed on in the client-side javascript.  It will look something like this:

```
<script>
window.App = {
  context: {
    dispatcher: {
      stores: {
        ApplicationStore: {
          csrf: "1234abcd",
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

[Here is the Html.jsx component in the Flux example.](https://github.com/yahoo/flux-examples/blob/master/react-router/components/Html.jsx#L33)

**If you are not creating an isomorphic application (the React components are run on the sever as well as the client) then I would suggest just to write out a script tag that contains the `csrf` token.**

For Fluxible that value is then [rehydrated on the client](https://github.com/yahoo/flux-examples/blob/master/react-router/client.js#L30).

```
var dehydratedState = window.App; // Sent from the server
var app = require('./app');

app.rehydrate(dehydratedState, function (err, context) {
  ...
});
```

Leaving you with a populated store on the client *without an additional http request*.  You can then access the `csrf` token from anywhere by accessing the store.

You can pass it via the context by doing something like this:

```
var componentContext = context.getComponentContext();
componentContext.csrf = req.csrfToken();

...

var markup = React.renderToString(Component({context: componentContext}))
```

You can then access it via the component's props.

`this.props.context.csrf`

If you are using Fluxible and want to pass it via the context I would maybe do it in a plugin, but you get the idea.

Full sever code:

```
/**
 * Copyright 2014, Yahoo! Inc.
 * Copyrights licensed under the New BSD License. See the accompanying LICENSE file for terms.
 */
require('babel/register');
var express = require('express');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var serialize = require('serialize-javascript');
var navigateAction = require('./actions/navigate');
var setCsrfTokenAction = require('./actions/setCsrfToken');
var debug = require('debug')('Example');
var React = require('react');
var app = require('./app');
var HtmlComponent = React.createFactory(require('./components/Html.jsx'));
var Router = require('react-router');

var server = express();
server.use(favicon(__dirname + '/../favicon.ico'));
server.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/build'));

server.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var context = app.createContext();

    debug('Executing navigate action');
    Router.run(app.getComponent(), req.path, function (Handler, state) {
        context.executeAction(setCsrfTokenAction, req.csrfToken(), function(){});
        context.executeAction(navigateAction, state, function () {
            debug('Exposing context state');
            var exposed = 'window.App=' + serialize(app.dehydrate(context)) + ';';

            debug('Rendering Application component into html');
            var Component = React.createFactory(Handler);
            var html = React.renderToStaticMarkup(HtmlComponent({
                state: exposed,
                markup: React.renderToString(Component({context:context.getComponentContext()}))
            }));

            debug('Sending markup');
            res.send(html);
        });
    });
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
```

Answer (score -3):

Passing stuff through the template into React is a bit fiddly. It might be better to simply set up an Ajax call for the CSRF token.

[This link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax) details how to do it with Django and jQuery, but the concepts should be pretty portable.